# Sonar issue - Remove this assignment of "k"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am getting this issue in sonar. I don't know why it's giving this issue.

[image]

The code is:

```
for(let k=0; k<this.side_list.length; ++k){
  if(this.allowedPageList.indexOf(this.side_list[k].route) === -1){
    this.side_list.splice(k,1); --k;
  }else{
    if(this.side_list[k].children?.length > 0){
      for(let l=0; l<this.side_list[k].children.length; ++l){
        if(this.allowedPageList.indexOf(this.side_list[k].children[l].route) === -1){
          this.side_list[k].children.splice(l,1); --l;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can somebody please help me fix this issue? Is sonar asking me to remove `--k` and `--l` from the code? But that can then disrupt the function.

Comment: Use `k++` , `k--` and `l--`

Comment: @Eliseo and `l++` too?

Comment: Yes, I've never seen the increment before the variable in a loop (really I've see the way ++variable when we can use the actual value and increment inmediatly, e.g. in a console.log(++variable)), but in any another case. My "logic" indicate that in your code will be the same result but I'm not pretty sure about this.

Comment: `I've never seen the increment before the variable in a loop` Bro that's not true. I think you need to read more about looping and post and pre increments.

Comment: Sure I need read more (I try always going learn). It's only a comment that I "saw it strange" (not that it's not OK)

Comment: Thinking about, the only wrong is the `1` in your "++ 1 k" (sorry about the before comments)

Comment: I haven't used sonarqube but I would guess it's complaining about reassigning a value that your `for` control-flow depends on. Probably considered bad practice because it could result in an infinite loop. Just a guess though. What does this have to do with angularjs?